# ajax uses previous results on my struts progress bar

Tags: java, ajax, struts, progress

i make ajax calls to retrieve the percent done uploading in struts. everything works fine on the first time i test uploading and my process bar will go from like 9% to 22% to 51% to 90% to 100% and then the next page loads as it should saying upload successful.

The problem is if I upload a 2nd file, say twice as big, it should use it's own percentage complete. but it instead, throws out 9%, 22%, 51% 90%, 100% and then finally gets its real percent of say 41% then goes to 45% but if it hits like 51% (from the first try), it jumps to 90% and then 100% again.

if i close and reopen the browser each time it works correctly, but if i upload more than once per session somehow it uses old values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is for the ajax cache.

```
Send a random number when calling ajax.
```

For Jquery ajax use

```
cache: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not clearing data that was set in the session after the upload is completed.

In particular, it is a problem at the server side. It looks like that the old file size is kept in the session and reused again to calculate the percentage. Just print (or log) the value of file size at the server side and you will figure it out ;)

Comment: hi. thanks for helping. it is not the file size for sure. i put printlns and they are different. i have everything as request scope only except this 'percent' complete. i even try to removeAttribute from the session or set it to null and nothing is working.